# electron-packager does not preserve file times

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I am working on an app that communicates with a device and, depending on the time stamps of files stored on that device and the time stamps of the resource files, will copy new files as needed.  I have noticed that, when I run electron-packager, the time stamps for ALL of the files in the generated package have the time when the packager was run.  It would appear that electron-packager, rather than simply copying the files, is reading them and rewriting them in the package directory.  Is there any way to make electron-packager preserve the time stamps of the source files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [`electron-packager`'s docs](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md), there does not seem to be a way to preserve timestamps.

As an alternative, you could check the hash of the file instead to determine if the file has been modified.